# linqToSql + linqToXMl - backup table in xml file

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

my problem is that I have list of XElements and honestly I have no idea what should I do to save it in file.

my method:

```
            XDocument xml = new XDocument();
        List<XElement> list = new List<XElement>();
        foreach (Visit v in BlogDB.Visits)
        {
            list.Add(new XElement("Visit",
                                        new XElement("id", v.id),
                                        new XElement("SessionID", v.SessionID),
                                        new XElement("StartDate", v.StartDate),
                                        new XElement("Date", v.Date),
                                        new XElement("IPAddress", v.IPAddress),
                                        new XElement("WhereIsHe", v.WhereIsHe),
                                        new XElement("WhoIs", v.WhoIs)));

        }
```

and now what? how to add this list to xml file?
I've tried:

```
xml.Add(from el in list select (XElement)el);
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case:

```
        List<XElement> list = new List<XElement>() { new XElement("first"), new XElement("Second") };
        XElement root = new XElement("root", list);
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Add(root);  // add it later to prevent the error mentioned below.
        doc.Save(Console.Out); // put in here the file name or Console.Out to see the contents directly in your window.
```

To create a valid Xml Document you need to add a root node to the Xml document.

Comment: I like your way but now I get exception: Non white space characters cannot be added to content.

Comment: According to this post: http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/bmains/archive/2009/07/25/linq-to-xml-non-white-space-characters-cannot-be-added-to-content.aspx you should first create the XDocument and add it later. I will adapt the code

Answer (score 1):

Add your list of XElements to the Xdocument, then call Save() on the document.

Maybe something like this.

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument(
   BlogDB.Visits.Select(v=>new XElement("Visit",
      new XElement("id", v.id),
      new XElement("SessionID", v.SessionID),
      new XElement("StartDate", v.StartDate),
      new XElement("Date", v.Date),
      new XElement("IPAddress", v.IPAddress),
      new XElement("WhereIsHe", v.WhereIsHe),
      new XElement("WhoIs", v.WhoIs))));
xml.Save("filename.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added elements to the document. To save this document to a file you need to call a Save method of the document:

xml.Save

Comment: hm, I'm getting: This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.